# CSS/Javascript/Jquery 3D Rotation animation without CSS3 Transform?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to flip an object in a 3D-type manner, but I want the animation to be available to IE8+, Firefox, Opera, etc.  Obviously just collapsing it horizontally won't work, because it won't skew the image properly.  Is there any way to distort only part of an image, so the part that is 'closer' will be wider and the "farther" part will be thinner?

Thanks!

Comment: It's an image? Then you can apply some canvas magic on it. If it's a normal DOM element, this is hardly possible.

Comment: It is, indeed, an image.  I've never done anything with canvas.  I intend to look into it either way, but out of curiosity is it going to be awful or pretty easy to do a basic rotation?

Comment: 2d rotation: easy; 3d rotation in 2d context: awful; 3d rotation: possible

Comment: Haha yeah, I've been looking into it.  By '3d rotation: possible' I'm getting the feeling you mean 'in theory'...I'm looking into using perspectiveTransform.js, which I discovered during my search.  Seems it may get the job done with enough putzing.

Comment: (Nope...might have worked if it weren't so bouncy)

Comment: With "3d" I meant WebGL context, which doesn't apply to the browsers you're working on so it's not an actual option :-) Btw, perspectiveTransform.js seems to rely on css3 which you're trying to prevent.